# Variable is changed but spinner still shows

Tags: reactjs

I have a small problem but it is confusing me.
In my render function in React component I am showing bootstrap spinner.
It only shows if isSaving is TRUE.

```
class Scorer extends Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.store     =     this.context.store;
        this.state     = {
            matchId:    props.match.params.id,
            isLoading:  true,
            isSaving:   false,
            saveStatus: "",
        };

        this.toggleSavingStatus   = this.toggleSavingStatus.bind(this);
        this.toggleLoadingStatus  = this.toggleLoadingStatus.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Get initial state from server
        console.log('Get Initial State from Server', this.state.isLoading);
        utilGetJSON('startup.php?matchId=' + this.state.matchId)
            .then((response) => {
                this.toggleLoadingStatus();

                this.store.dispatch({
                    type:       constants.INITIAL_STATE,
                    payload:    response.data
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('axios.get ERROR', error);
                this.toggleLoadingStatus();
            });
    }


    toggleLoadingStatus() {
        this.setState = ({
            isLoading: !this.state.isLoading,
        }, ()=>{
            console.log('Flag toggle Loading: ', this.state.isLoading);
        });
    }
    toggleSavingStatus() {

        this.setState = ({
            isSaving: !this.state.isSaving,
        }, ()=>{
            console.log('Flag toggle Saving:', this.state.isSaving);
        });
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState){
        saveStateToServer(nextState.store.getState(), this.toggleSavingStatus);
        const stateSavedObj = getStateSavedObj(nextState.store.getState());

        if ( stateSavedObj !== null ){
            const lastSavedDate = new Date(stateSavedObj.timestamp * 1000);
            this.setState({
                saveStatus: "Match last saved on server at "+lastSavedDate.toLocaleString()
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.state.isLoading &&
                    <div className="text-center text-danger">
                        <i className="fa fa-spinner fa-spin font-md" aria-hidden="true"></i><br/>Loading</div>
                }
                { this.state.isSaving &&
                <div className="text-center text-danger">
                    <i className="fa fa-spinner fa-spin font-md" aria-hidden="true"></i><br/>Saving on server</div>
                }
                { this.state.saveStatus !== '' && !this.state.isSaving &&
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="bs-callout bs-callout-danger text-danger">
                        {this.state.saveStatus}
                    </div>
                </div>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Scorer.contextTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object
};
```

*I have reduced this class for simplicity*.
Now I call other function that sets the flag to FALSE. Console.log confirms it but still spinner is showing up.

```
Get Initial State from Server true
Scorer.js:53 toggleLoadingStatus() called
Scorer.js:57 Flag toggle Loading:  true
```

I dont understand. In angular (in which I have always worked). I can easily hide spinner by just setting variable to false.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React you should use component state your code should look like that :

```
class Scorer extends Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            isSaving: false
        }
        this.toggleSavingStatus  = this.toggleSavingStatus.bind(this);
    }

    toggleSavingStatus() {
        this.setState({
            isSaving : !this.state.isSaving
        },()=>{
           console.log('Flag toggle', this.state.isSaving);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ScoreAction />
                { this.state.isSaving &&
                <div className="text-center text-danger">
                    <i className="fa fa-spinner fa-spin font-md" aria-hidden="true"></i><br/>Saving on server</div>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

One final edit its better to use the callback function of `setState` to check the new updated state value, because in some situation you might log the old state as `setState` function is asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used state in most of my classes but here I guess I just used variables. So I should never ever use variables in react like this? Only state ?

Comment: Yes because react will depend on the component state to know when it should update or render again ... so you should always use state, and keep in mind to use setState function to update the component state don't try to use this.state.isSaving = !this.state.isSaving instead use this.setState({ isSaving: !this.state.isSaving })

Comment: If I move all my variables into state then I get this error at the start of the app `inst.setState.bind is not a function` and `axios.get ERROR TypeError: this.setState is not a function`

Comment: I need to check the rest of the code to be able to figure this out ... but i am guessing that you are missing a function binding ... probably you are calling ```this``` inside a function with a different ```this``` scope you might need to bind the ```axios.get``` callback function to ```this```

Comment: YES I fixed `this.setState` error by calling a function instead of directly setting state `this.setState` in the `.then` of *axios*. But for some odd reason, still spinner does not hide.

Comment: I can update question to include entire component. It is not much.

Comment: I have added entire source.

Comment: Yes you just have a typo in the ```toggleLoadingStatus``` function it should be ```this.setState({isLoading : !this.state.isLoading})``` not ```this.setState = (...```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that isSaving is a class variable, and even when you change its value, it doesn't trigger a `rerender`. I suggest you keep this value in state, and `setState`.

```
class Scorer extends Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {isSaving:false}
        this.toggleSavingStatus  = this.toggleSavingStatus.bind(this);
    }

    toggleSavingStatus() {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({isSaving: !prevState.isSaving}))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ScoreAction />
                { this.isSaving &&
                <div className="text-center text-danger">
                    <i className="fa fa-spinner fa-spin font-md" aria-hidden="true"></i><br/>Saving on server</div>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

There is not problem keeping a value in state until you want to change its value from render, because then it would go in a loop. In that case you can keep it in a variable and do a `forceUpdate` when you actually need to and not on every change.

Comment: @Amr you need to bind your functions properly

Comment: I have used setState but still it is not working. Unfortunately.